# Why is multiprocessing Pool.join() taking so long?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have the following function which I am trying to execute in parallel for each sample using multiprocessing. Overall it is taking around 8 seconds. When I print the time elapsed after each line of code (including those in the 'irl' function), every line is relatively small (< 1s) but the pool.join() line takes around 7 seconds. This doesn't seem correct, is something wrong in the code?

```
def batch_irl(feat, future_traj, r_out, mdp, grid_size):
    n_sample = feat.shape[0]
    result = []
    pool = Pool(processes=n_sample)
    for i in range(n_sample):
        r_sample = r_out[i].squeeze().reshape(mdp.n_states)
        future_traj_sample = future_traj[i]  # choose one sample from the batch
        future_traj_sample = 
future_traj_sample[~np.isnan(future_traj_sample).any(axis=1)]  # remove appended NAN rows
        future_traj_sample = future_traj_sample.astype(np.int64)
        result.append(pool.apply_async(irl, args=(future_traj_sample, r_sample, mdp, grid_size)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # Extract result and stack svf_diffs for backpropagation through the network
    nll_list = [result[i].get()[0] for i in range(n_sample)]
    svf_diff_list = [result[i].get()[1] for i in range(n_sample)]
    values_list = [result[i].get()[2] for i in range(n_sample)]
    svf_diff_batch = np.concatenate(svf_diff_list, axis=0)
    return svf_diff_batch, nll_list, values_list
```

Comment: It is possible that your objects are huge (are they?) and processing time is heavily outweighted by (de)serialization time.

Comment: Well, timing the code in `batch_irl` prior to `pool.join` isn't really relevant, as that's all just code related to *starting* your parallel processes. You don't show `irl`, but the overhead to *get* to `pool.join` *should* be relatively low; all the real work is being done elsewhere, and `pool.join` blocks until that is done.

Comment: I have also timed each line within `irl` though. Is this still related to starting the parallel processes or will it be the actual execution time? If it is the latter I'm not sure what's taking so much time as the time for `irl` is only around a second